# C++ LPSTR and string trouble with zero-terminated strings

Tags: c++, string, winapi, stdstring, getopenfilename

I'm using `GetOpenFileName` function from `Winapi`, and I'm applying filter to the select file dialog.

**THIS** works perfectly:

```
LPSTR mfilter = "Filter\0*.PDF\0";
ofn.lpstrFilter = mfilter;

if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn)){
...
```

[image]

**THIS** fails (dialog opens but no filters apply):

```
string mfilter = "Filter\0*.PDF\0";
ofn.lpstrFilter = mfilter.c_str();

if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn)){
...
```

[image]

I need to use `std:string` because I'm getting the file extension via parameters and this type facilitates the concatenation but I'm getting incompatibility issues...

This would be my code if it worked as expected (IT FAILS the same as previous example):

```
const char * ext = &(4:); //Ampersand parameter (from CA Plex) It contains "PDF"
string mfilter = "Filter\0*." + ext + "\0"; //Final string: Filter\0*.PDF\0;
ofn.lpstrFilter = mfilter.c_str();
```

When I use this method, I'm getting runtime exception:

```
string mf;
mf.append("Filter")
.append('\0')
.append("*.pdf")
.append('\0');

ofn.lpstrFilter = mf.c_str();
```

[image]

Comment: If you set a breakpoint and you inspect mfilter buffer what you see? (before crash...)

Comment: Whenever I have to work with MFC/WinAPI I always use the MSism way. Fighting it is not worth the effort.

Comment: If you won't show a [mcve] I doubt this is going to be productive. I can guess that you modify the string, or destroy it, and so render the pointer invalid.

Comment: And so it proves to be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34223930/c-simple-if-clause-changes-value-of-a-static-const-char-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetOpenFileName` function uses TCHARs, and TCHARs become WCHARs in case of **UNICODE** character set is used.

Here's an example:

```
std::wstring getOpenFileName(HWND hWnd, const std::wstring& sFilter)
{
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH] = L"";

    OPENFILENAMEW ofn = {0};

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = sFilter.c_str();
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFile = buffer;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    if( !::GetOpenFileNameW( &ofn ) )
        return L"";

    return buffer;
}
```

If you want to parametrize `lpstrFilter` based on `std::wstring` you can just use `wstring::c_str()` to get `LPCTSTR` which is `const wchar*` in case of **UNICODE**.

**IMPORTANT:** The problem is that the `std::wstring` constructor that takes a `const wchar*` assumes the input is a C string. C strings are '\0' terminated and thus parsing stops when it reaches the '\0' character. To compensate for this you need to use the **constructor that takes two parameters a pointer to the char array and a length**.
You can also use `string::push_back()` method to append NULLs.

```
std::wstring sFilter = L"PDF Files";
sFilter.push_back('\0');
sFilter.append(L"*.pdf");
sFilter.push_back('\0');
```

Comment: The only issue I've got is setting `ofn.lpstrFilter` dynamically. A file extension is passed via a parameter and I need to apply that extension filter to the dialog when it opens. As I can see you are setting the filters as a literal string and that's the way it worked for me as the first example shows, but it isn't a solution. How would you set a filter string dynamically with a parameter always keeping null-terminators? Thanks.

Comment: This is not the answer. It is obvious from the working examples in the question that the OP is only using ANSI functions.

Comment: It is not obvious et al. In 2015 using ASCII char-set and not using UNICODE is a crime.

Comment: I've updated the answer to describe the way to parametrize lpstrFilter

Comment: Asker has runtime error. Whether or not ANSI is a crime in 2015, you do need to address the actual issue.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Totally agree. That was my mistake. I've updated the answer to address the actual issue.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin Your answer worked! I was going crazy with this. Just one last thing, `std::wstring sFilter = L"PDF Files";` sets "3DF Files" to the dialog filter, I'm assuming the first character of the string is converted, also tried other string and it happens the same. I'm getting "˫PG" in "JPG" example.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid: I guess the problem is that your project uses **MBCS** (Multi-Byte character set) and you should be using **UNICODE**. So just change project settings to use Unicode Character Set.

Comment: Nothing here makes sense. The only thing that makes sense is that the string is modified after `c_str()` is called, thus invalidating the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
string mfilter = "Filter\0*.PDF\0";
```

you are calling an `std::string` contructor, which terminates the string at the first `\0`.

The following code:

```
string mfilter = "Filter\0*.PDF\0";
cout << "string:" << mfilter << "   len: " << mfilter.length() << endl;
```

prints

```
string: Filter   len: 6
```

The string is only constructed until the first `\0` terminator. Do the string is only composed of the word "Filter".

Comment: Added examples. Thanks.

Comment: Is the use of embedded NULs in `std::string` even defined? If it turns out that you really cannot do that with `std::string`, (to answer your question below) you will need to use good old fashioned memory allocation and `strcpy()`...

Comment: @andlabs I don't know what you mean when saying that I need to define "the use of embedded NULs"

Comment: You don't need to define anything, the C++ standard does. Everything I've found though indicates that yes, you can use NUL with a `std::string`. You will need to either show your full code or use a debugger.

Comment: I'm not able to use a debugger due to I'm working on an IDE which doesn't allow it (yes, unbelievable). I don't mind showing my full code but the issue is located where I'm saying, when trying to form a "filter" to that Winapi function it doesn't understand it and does whatever it wants, quite common from Windows API.

Comment: To construct a `std::string` from a string literal that has embedded nulls in it, you need to specify the literal's actual length to the constructor, eg: `string mfilter("Filter\0*.PDF\0", 13);`

Answer (score 0):

```
string mfilter = "Filter\0*.PDF\0";
```

This calls a `std::basic_string` constructor that uses *a null-terminated string*. It will stop parsing the string literal at `"Filter"`.

Try this one instead:

```
string mfilter( "Filter\0*.PDF", 13 ); // need double null at end
```

This calls a `std::basic_string` constructor that uses *"the first count characters of character string pointed to by s. **s can contain null characters**."*

You have to either count the characters yourself, or write wrapper code if you encounter this problem more often.

---

Related: [`std::basic_string` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

---

As for your runtime error:

```
string mf;
mf.append("Filter")
.append('\0')
.append("*.pdf")
.append('\0');
```

`append()` [*does not have* an overload for a single character type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append). You are probably hitting the `const CharT* s` overload, with a null pointer.

Use either `append( 1, '\0' )` or `append( "", 1 )`, either of which should append a null byte.

Comment: `string mfilter( "Filter\0*.PDF", 12 );` needs to be `string mfilter( "Filter\0*.PDF\0", 13 );` instead, because `GetOpenFileName()` expects the filter to be **double** null terminated.  `c_str()` will add one null terminator for you, but the data needs to contain the other null terminator.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I enjoyed being able to stay *well* clear of WinAPI in my career so far. ;) Thanks for the heads-up. But since the string literal comes with an implicit zero at the end, I don't have to add one, just up the count. (Or does `c_str()` skip the adding then?)

Comment: A count of 12 does not include the implicit null. You have to bump the count to 13, whether the final null is implicit or explicit. `c_str()` always includes its own null at the end of whatever the `std::string` is actually holding.